# Generating random words

Tags: python, random

I'm trying to create a string that has a set amount of different words I include in a list, however the code I use only uses one word at random, not a different word for every word printed.

This is my code:

```
import random

words = ['hello', 'apple', 'something', 'yeah', 'nope', 'lalala']
print random.choice(words) * 5
```

An example output would be:

`hellohellohellohellohello`

An example expected output would be:

`appleyeahhellonopesomething`

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: "multiplying" a string will print the string multiple times. E.g., `print '=' * 30` would print a line of 30 "=", that's why you are getting 5 times "hello"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`random.choice(words) * 5` executes `random.choice` only once and then multiplies the result by five, causing the same string to be repeated.

```
>>> import random
>>> words = ['hello', 'apple', 'something', 'yeah', 'nope', 'lalala']
>>> print ''.join(random.choice(words) for _ in range(5))
applesomethinghellohellolalala
```

Comment: Is the `_` called an anonymous variable? (I know we don't need the value that variable per se, it's really just an unnamed placeholder), so I'm wondering about the correct term.

Comment: @Levon I don't know any more than what you have just said about `_`.

Comment: Ah ok, I was just trying to figure out the "official" name for doing this :)

Comment: `sample()` (as suggested below) is probably a better way.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't want the words from your original list to be repeated, then you could use `sample`.

```
import random as rn
words = ['hello', 'apple', 'something', 'yeah', 'nope', 'lalala']

word = ''.join(rn.sample(words, 5))
```

Result:

```
>>> word
'yeahhellosomethingapplenope'
```

Answer (score 3):

You aren't calling `random.choice(words)` 5 times, you are getting an output of `random.choice(words)` and then multiplying in 5 times. With strings, it just repeats the string.

`"abc" * 3` would give you `"abcabcabc"`

So depending on your randomly chosen word first, it just gets repeated 5 times.

Answer (score 2):

"multiplying" a string will print the string multiple times. E.g., `print '=' * 30` would print a line of 30 `"="`, that's why you are getting 5 times `"hello"` - it repeats the randomly chosen word 5 times.

```
import random, sys
words = ['hello', 'apple', 'something', 'yeah', 'nope', 'lalala']

for i in range(5):
    sys.stdout.write(random.choice(words))
```

using [choice()](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html?highlight=choice#random.choice) will give you a set of 5 random selections. Note we use `sys.std.write` to the avoid the space successive `print` statements would put between words.

e.g., from two runs:

```
yeahsomethinghelloyeahlalala
```

and

```
somethingyeahsomethinglalalanope
```

> `choice()`
>
> Return a random element from the non-empty sequence seq. If seq is
>   empty, raises IndexError.

Of course in Python 3.x, we could use `print` instead of `sys.stdout.write` and set its `end` value to `''`. I.e.,

```
print(random.choice(words), end='')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import random
WORDS = ("Python","Java","C++","Swift","Assembly")
for letter in WORDS:
    position = random.randrange(len(WORDS))
    word = WORDS[position]
    print(word)
```