# Generating a list of segmented random words from a list

Tags: python, random

I got this from here: [Generating random words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11166547/generating-random-words)

```
import random

words = ['hello', 'apple', 'something', 'yeah', 'nope', 'lalala'] 

''.join(random.sample(words, 10))
```

> applesomethinghellohellolalala

How do I segment the random words so that I can get the below result?

> words = ['apple', 'something', 'hello', 'hello', 'lala']

Comment: By getting rid of the `''.join`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import random

words = ['hello', 'apple', 'something', 'yeah', 'nope', 'lalala']
print [random.sample(words, 1)[0] for i in range(10)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
random.sample(words, 1)[0]
```

as Eugeny proposed, I'd rather use `random.choice`:

```
print [random.choice(words) for i in range(10)]
```